# Run ssh login command without modifying remote .bashrc

Tags: bash, ssh, bashrc

We have a bunch of servers set up with `set -o vi` in their `~/.bashrc`.

It would be nice to be able to ssh into these boxes and automagically run `set -o emacs` as a timesave.

I've seen a solution indicating that such additions should be made on the remote host `~/.bashrc` but we cannot modify these for various reasons.

Another solution suggests using:

`spawn ssh -t user@host "set -o emacs; /bin/bash -i"`

..but I understand this requires running the `expect` shell instead of plain `bash`.

Is there a simple way to achieve this goal? Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is there an issue changing `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: What is the *`expect`* shell? I know of the *`expect TCL`-based* command language often (mis?)used to automate secure logons and such - is this what you mean? Also - and this is a shot in the dark - but how do you find *`ssh user@host '( set -o ; /bin/bash -i /otherrc )'`* works for you?

Answer (score 4):

```
ssh -t user@host bash -o emacs -i
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Because there's a command in `.bashrc` that overrides it?  Add `--norc`, or `--rcfile yourfile.rc` instead.

Comment: As I said in my original post there is `set -o vi` in every server `.bashrc`. I did as you suggested, inserting `--norc` immediately after `bash` in your above command. The parameter was clearly applied since the bash prompt presented appeared different, however emacs keybindings were still not enabled.

Comment: If you have `set -o vi` in your profile files too (or they source `.bashrc`), you might need: `ssh -t user@host bash --norc --noprofile -o emacs -i`

Comment: Thank you for yet another suggestion Jim. Unfortunately this one didn't work either! I'm thinking this may not be possible, it's certainly frustrating to have tried so many approaches without success.

Comment: Weird, it should definitely work -- I made a setup like yours here and tested it.  What version of bash are you running?  What's the output of `set -o` in your shell after logging in?

Answer (score 2):

Start bash with the `--rcfile` option and specify a different bashrc. For example, write a file called `~/.bashrc-emacs` that contains

```
. ~/.bashrc
set -o emacs
```

and run

```
ssh -t user@host bash --rcfile=.bashrc-emacs
```

You can use `--norc` to skip reading `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` altogether. Bash is in emacs mode by default.

If you do want to read the remote `.bashrc` and you don't want to write to any file on the server, I think expect is your best bet.

Comment: Or even something like *`grep -v 'set -o vi' /etc/bash.bashrc | ( exec bash -i  <&0 )`* might work.

Answer (score 2):

I realize you mentioned not to edit .bashrc. However, I hope this might help someone else. I have been looking for a good answer to a similar problem for many years. I like to use vi but don't want to change the default for everyone else.

Edit /etc/ssh/ssh_config in your local configuration and add the following line:

```
SendEnv EDITOR
```

You can use any environment variable but EDITOR seems like a good choice. In my case EDITOR is set to vim.

In the remote system, edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add the following line:

```
AcceptEnv EDITOR
```

Edit .bashrc or .bash_profile and add the following:

```
if [ "$EDITOR" = "vim" ]; then
         set -o vi;
fi
```

For the use case in this question, replace vi with emacs.
Note: You might need to restart sshd in the target system.