# byobu prevents SSH login

Tags: bash, ssh, byobu

I'm running arch linux for arm on an old goflex for network storage and wanted to use byobu on it. There's no package for the distribution so I compiled it from source, and it works just fine. The main issue is that when I ran byobu-enable, it changed my .bash_profile from

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

to

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
_byobu_sourced=1 . /usr/local/bin/byobu-launch 2>/dev/null || true
```

And now when I try to use ssh I get a permission denied error. Any way to fix this so that I can get byobu to launch on login without breaking ssh?

For what it's worth, my bashrc is

```
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

alias ls='ls --color=auto'
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
[ -r /home/alarm/.byobu/prompt ] && . /home/alarm/.byobu/prompt   #byobu-prompt#
```

Here is a verbose `ssh` connection attempt showing the error:

```
pgcudahy$ ssh -vv alarm@192.168.1.76
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.1.76 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.76 [192.168.1.76] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.76:22 as 'alarm'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:vMgm5NL3fsrwxXI0MUV7Pz8g4nrZ8u4ecpfoQGvjPWY
debug1: Host '192.168.1.76' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/known_hosts:24
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:hGZ9c/Bh8R3LxHOxm2X3nPO6RyRgeejjeVeDYTTkPI4
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:hGZ9c/Bh8R3LxHOxm2X3nPO6RyRgeejjeVeDYTTkPI4
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/pgcudahy/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:hGZ9c/Bh8R3LxHOxm2X3nPO6RyRgeejjeVeDYTTkPI4
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.76 ([192.168.1.76]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /home/alarm/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/alarm/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o3 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 192.168.1.76 closed.
Transferred: sent 3076, received 2924 bytes, in 4.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 692.8, received 658.5
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? At what point does it arise? Does it stop you logging in remotely?

Comment: I've added the error message. In the end I get "Connection to 192.168.1.76 closed". I can still use ssh to send commands, so I can send 'byobu-disable' and regain interactive ssh access.

Comment: That's unfortunately completely illegible on a mobile. Can you repeat it (or replace it) with a non-debug version please. (Don't use backticks. Instead, select the block and use the {} code block formatter, which indents each line by four spaces.)

Comment: I also can't see any Permission Denied in that ssh connection. Currently your description doesn't match your symptoms.

Comment: if you're actually having trouble logging in because of the bashrc, try the suggestion in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55651/117549